# Draggable image with pinch to zoom in mobile web app

Tags: javascript, easeljs, hammer.js

I am working on a project where I am trying to make a draggable image with  pinch to zoom feature inside a canvas in a mobile web app. I am using EaselJS to make it draggable and HammerJS to add pinch to zoom feature. But it does not work smoothly and when zooming the image it sometimes jumps to a different location.

The code I am using for Hammer JS pinch to zoom.

```
    hammerTime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });
    hammerTime.on('pinchstart', function() {
        last_scale = scale;
    });
    hammerTime.on('pinchin pinchout', function(evt) {
        scale = last_scale * evt.scale;
        bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = scale;

        shouldUpdateCanvas = true;
    });
```

EaselJS code for making it draggable.

```
     bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(originalImage);

    // Bind the image events (draggable).
    bitmap.addEventListener('mousedown', function(evt) {
        var currentTarget = evt.currentTarget;
        var localPoint = currentTarget.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
        var newX = currentTarget.regX - localPoint.x;
        var newY = currentTarget.regY - localPoint.y;

        //set the new regX/Y and then adjust the real-position, otherwise the new regX/Y would cause a jump.
        currentTarget.regX = localPoint.x;
        currentTarget.x -= newX;
        currentTarget.regY = localPoint.y;
        currentTarget.y -= newY;
    });


    bitmap.addEventListener('pressmove', function(evt) {
        evt.currentTarget.x = evt.stageX;
        evt.currentTarget.y = evt.stageY;

        shouldUpdateCanvas = true;
    });
```

I was also not able to find good documentation on HammerJS. I want to know what exactly is pinchstart doing in the code. I am hoping making some changes with HammerJS could help me avoid jumping of the image during zooming. Any help will be appreciated.